# "brew tap mongodb/brew " results in "fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision"

Tags: mongodb, terminal, homebrew

I am trying to tap/install mongodb and I am having this issue:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

results in `fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision`

Answer (score 1):

Faced a similar issue in homebrew as below,

```
Searching taps on GitHub... Error: No formulae found in taps
```

had run this command to update the branch as master, which fixed the issue:

```
git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master
```

for troubleshooting the following command helps:
***brew doctor***